# Manually start Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle

I have a Oracle DB in my computer, but when i have this DB my computer start very slowly. I decide to disable Oracle services in msconfig. I disable a follow services:

OracleMTSRecoveryService

OracleServiceXE

OracleXEClrAgent

OracleXETNSListener

But sometimes I need using a Oracle Database. I try run in windows admin tools in services. I run all Oracle services:

OracleJobScheduler
OracleMTSRecoveryService

OracleServiceXE

OracleXEClrAgent

OracleXETNSListener

All services have state set a running.

But when i run SQL Developer and try connect to my database i get this error:

> > An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
>   01033. 00000 -  "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress" Cause: An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up
>              or shutdown. Action: Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation. Vendor code 1033

Why? How to correctly run database in manually case?

Comment: The message says "wait a few minutes". How long did you wait?

Comment: Did you check the **alert log**? Or tried anything, at least after google search? You must narrow down to some basic troubleshooting before posting such a broad question. There could be numerous issues. Remember, always mention your **OS** details and **DB version** details. The troubleshooting steps depends on the **Operating system**. And do you have **SYS** privilege?

Comment: I'll note that according to your question you disabled four services but you're enabling/running five services. I suggest you go back in and re-enable all the services you disabled, then reboot. If that doesn't get Oracle working properly again your best bet is to uninstall Oracle and re-install it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Login to sqlplus as SYSDBA (for instance with "sqlplus /as SYSDBA" on command line).
It probably says "connected to an idle instance". In that case , you can start the database with "startup". 
Because you have been fiddling with the startup services there might be other steps to take. But based on your information anything can be wrong.